# Android: Is it possible to base a GridView on an adapter with filter capabaility?

Tags: android, gridview, filter, adapter

**BACKGROUND:**
I have a **GridView** based on a fairly complex **Adapter** class which extends **BaseAdapter**.  I find that I am doing much too much work in **getView** to calculate what to display and that often the number of items I want to display changes during those calculations.  **getView** even gets called multiple times for the same position.  It just seems like **notifyDataSetChanged()** gets called too soon.

This has caused much pain in my coding.  I moved most of the code out into other routines, but find I still need to do some filtering of selections during the final display.

I've worked around this by setting the **item.enabled(false)**, which works, but I'd rather eliminate the item all together.

I can't find a lifecycle for the **GridView** & underlying adapter, but I have determined that **getCount()** gets called a number of times before the items are displayed and while I can hook my changes in there, it just feels like I am having to work too hard here.

**QUESTION:**
Can I use a **Filter** class in connections with an **Adapter** tied to a **GridView**?

For example, my Adapter for the **GridView** has 36 items to display, and the Activity which contains it has a **TextView** set to value "3" which means only show every 3rd item. **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** gets called and immediately **.getCount()** wants to return 36, which really messes with **getView**

I know there are not a lot of specifics here, because I need to understand the concepts, not just find a solution for a specific problem.

There must be some functionality or way of looking at the problem that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you overridden `getCount`? Why would it return 36 after the underlying data has changed?

If you make `getCount` depend on the underlying data I don't think you would have this problem:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myArray.length; // or whatever your underlying data source is
}
```

**Edit** - Also, make sure you make changes to your data set *before* calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.